# Exceptions not being handled correctly with MongoDB Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication, exception, driver

I'm having an issue with the MongoDB Java driver (Using driver version 3.0.4 and MongoDB version 3.2.3). I'm trying to check whether a connection opens to the MongoDB server and throw an exception if not. I should be able to catch it with:

```
servName = "Username";
servPW = "Password";

try {
    MongoCredential cred = MongoCredential.createCredential(servName, "DatabaseName", servPW.toCharArray());

    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017), Arrays.asList(cred));

} catch (MongoException e){
    System.out.println("ERROR");
}

System.out.println("WE ARE HERE");
```

The problem I'm having is that the exception that is thrown isn't caught, it seems to be coming from a thread that I can't access maybe? For testing I don't have a Mongo server running just to see the exception that gets thrown. Similar to the issue in this question ([MongoDB java driver 3.0 can't catch exception when authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090906/mongodb-java-driver-3-0-cant-catch-exception-when-authenticate/35747228?noredirect=1#comment59167973_35747228)). This is the output:

> Mar 02, 2016 12:24:17 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger
>   log
>       INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN,
>   serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
>       WE ARE HERE
>       Mar 02, 2016 12:24:18 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
>       INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
>       com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)   at
>   com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
>     at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
>     ... 3 more

I've tried to catch "com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException", "Exception" and a number of others but nothing seems to work! Is anybody able to help me with where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)` -- Looks like your exception is being thrown in another thread. You'll have to `catch` it there.

Comment: Comes after WE ARE HERE is printed, so the try/catch you posted is obviously not the place where it's happening.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, the thread that is run is coming from the MongoDB driver library though. Any idea on how I could access the thread and catch it? Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find an answer to this question and couldn't work it out myself. In order to work around this issue I downgraded to driver version 2.11.1 and used that!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, the move to Mongo 3 drivers alters the behaviour of creating a Mongo Client - it becomes a non-blocking operation and you only find out whether you actually have a working connection when you try to use it.

The video I watched about this (https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-drivers-and-high-availability-deep-dive ) suggests using the client immediately after creating it to check whether it has been successful - it recommends using the command that asks whether or not the connected server is the "master" ( not sure what this is in Java ) .